# How to update the cached data when there is change in apidata Reactnative?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I am trying to cache the api data and fetch it when there is no internet connection. I am getting the data from cache but I am unable to update the data of cache when there is change of data in the api. Also how to check if there no internet connection and load data from cache?  I have implemented as follows:

```
export default class ViewpagerP extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLoading: true, data: [], isConnected: true }
}


async componentDidMount() {

    const photoStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('GalleryPhotos')
    console.log(photoStorage);
    if (!photoStorage) {
        try {
            console.log("Null inside")
            const photoResp = await axios.get('https://www.kitabjatra.com/api/event')
            console.log(photoResp)
            const photoData = await JSON.stringify(photoResp.data);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('GalleryPhotos', photoData);
            const datas = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('GalleryPhotos'));
            this.setState({ data: datas, isLoading: false })
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn("fetch Error: ", error)
        }
    } else {
        this.getPhotos();
    }
}
getPhotos = async () => {
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('GalleryPhotos'));
        this.setState({ data: data, isLoading: false })
        console.log(data);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

render() {

        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
                    <ActivityIndicator />
                </View>
            )
        }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ImageSlider style={styles.viewPagerStyle}
                loopBothSides
                autoPlayWithInterval={3000}
                images={this.state.data}
                customSlide={({ index, item, style, width }) => (
                    <View key={index} style={[style, styles.customSlideStyle]}>
                        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
                            <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} style={styles.customImage} />
                            <View style={styles.textContainerStyle}>
                                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item.event_title}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                )
                }

            />

        </View>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: You are fetching data on `componentDidMount` which will get called only once.

Comment: At which lifecycle should I fetch data?

Comment: It depends on your needs, when you want it

Comment: At my condition where should I call fetch data?

Comment: @SanyamJain Please explain

Comment: @SanyamJain I need to check if there is change in api data, if changed I should update the cache data if not changed show the cache data as it is.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. You have to hit your api after some interval again and again and you have to compare your data, if its different update cache else not.